# Is it possible to load a YouTube video with its API without embedding the actual video from YouTube onto a different site?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Example: https://piped.kavin.rocks/

I wanted to make it so the user can load a video if they have the link to it, but not load the embed from the actual site itself. Can anybody help?

Reason: My school restricts YouTube videos if they are in a certain category. The example website above will soon be restricted, so I'm trying to recreate it.

Thanks in advance.